# Mysql - duplicate entry error for key with auto increment

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Why do I get an error of the form:

`Error in query: Duplicate entry '10' for key 1`

...when doing an INSERT statement like:

`INSERT INTO wp_abk_period  (pricing_id, apartment_id)  VALUES (13, 27)`

...with 13 and 27 being valid id-s for existing `pricing` and `apartment` rows, and the table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_abk_period` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `apartment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pricing_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('available','booked','unavailable') collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `starts` datetime default NULL,
  `ends` datetime default NULL,
  `recur_type` enum('daily','weekly','monthly','yearly') collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `recur_every` char(3) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `timedate_significance` char(4) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `check_in_times` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `check_out_times` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `fk_period_apartment1_idx` (`apartment_id`),
  KEY `fk_period_pricing1_idx` (`pricing_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_period_apartment1` FOREIGN KEY (`apartment_id`) REFERENCES `wp_abk_apartment` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_period_pricing1` FOREIGN KEY (`pricing_id`) REFERENCES `wp_abk_pricing` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Isn't `key 1` `id` in this case and having it on `auto_increment` sufficient for being able to not specify it?

Note: If I just provide an unused value for `id`, like `INSERT INTO wp_abk_period  (id, pricing_id, apartment_id)  VALUES (3333333, 13, 27)` it works fine, but then again, it is set as `auto_increment` so I shouldn't need to do this!

---

Note 2: **OK, this is a complete "twilight zone" moment:** so after running the query above with the huge number for `id`, things started working normally, no more `duplicate entry errors`. **Can someone explain me WTF was MySQL doing to produce this weird behavior?**

Comment: It there an INSERT trigger on this table?

Comment: no (or at least I don't think so). I created all the tables myself with create statements as above. The output of `show create table wp_abk_period` is listed above and `show triggers` returns nothing... also, if I just provide an unused value for `id` it works fine...

Answer (score 16):

It could be that your AUTO_INCREMENT value for the table and the actual values in `id` column have got out of whack.

This might help:

**Step 1 - Get Max id from table**

```
select max(id) from wp_abk_period
```

**Step 2 - Align the AUTO_INCREMENT counter on table**

```
ALTER TABLE wp_abk_period AUTO_INCREMENT = <value from step 1 + 100>;
```

**Step 3 - Retry the insert**

As for *why* the AUTO_INCREMENT has got out of whack I don't know. Added auto_increment after data was in the table? Altered the auto_increment value after data was inserted into the table?

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! unfortunately neither (1) "Added auto_increment after data was in the table" nor (2) "Altered the auto_increment value after data was inserted into the table?" happened as far as I can tell, so some other "misterious" stuff hapened and I'm trying to prevent it from happening again now...

Comment: When I did this, the MySQL started a repair job on the table, which was probably the issue - the table was messed up and the primary key went out of sync with the `auto_increment` value (it was definitely not correct when I did `show create`)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and here is my solution :

My ID column had a bad parameter. It was Tinyint, and MySql want to write a 128th line.

Sometimes, your problem you think the bigger you have is only a tiny parameter...

Comment: For those who need this, you fix it with `alter table my_table auto_increment=1, modify column my_id integer not null auto_increment;` This resets the auto_increment to the highest value + 1, and recreates the column with an auto_increment field.

Comment: Thanks! I was going crazy wondering why my column's ids were just _stopping_ at 127. I had to drop a couple of foreign keys referencing my table first, and then update those columns to INT as well before re-creating the FKs.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but I just ran into this tonight - duplicate key '472817' and the provided answers didn't help.

On a whim I ran:

```
repair table wp_abk_period
```

which output

```
Number of rows changed from 472816 to 472817
```

Seems like mysql had the row count wrong, and the issue went away.

My environment:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for Win64 (unknown)
```

Create table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `env_events` (
  `tableId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deviceId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temperature` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `humidity` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `pressure` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `motion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tableId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=528521 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit about what table engine, key type, indexes were you using? For others to know *when* does mysql get row counting wrong, as this seems like a **big bug** if truly so. Or better, it would be great to actually report the bug to them (mysql or mariadb teams I mean)...

Comment: I'm using an older version of mysql in a dev environment, so I don't assume the engine to work flawless.

Comment: 'Late' is relative. I used this to fix our database two days ago. So thanks :)

Comment: doesn't work for Innodb

Answer (score 3):

You can check the current value of the auto_increment with the following command:

```
show table status
```

Then check the max value of the id and see if it looks right. If not change the auto_increment value of your table.

Comment: Useful. Showed me I'd zapped the auto_increment with an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging this problem check the table name [case sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) (especially if you run MySql not on Windows).
E.g. if one script uses upper case to 'CREATE TABLE my_table' and another script tries to 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE'. These 2 tables might have different contents and different file system locations which might lead to the described problem.